# Determining number of subscribers to a TransformBroadcaster

Tags: ros, geometry, transform-broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I determine the number of subscribers to my TransformBroadcaster?

Usually when you do a Publisher, you can call Publisher::getNumSubscribers() to determine if you want to publish that message. The nice thing about it is, if there is no one subscribed, you don't have to go through the effort of building and publishing the message.

Looking at the [code](https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry/file/d63770d2d475/tf/include/tf/transform_broadcaster.h), the underlying publisher used by TransformBroadcaster is private and there appears to be no way to access it. Plus it appears to never check number of subscribers before building and publishing the transform. Am I missing something? Is there another way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29925/determining-number-of-subscribers-to-a-transformbroadcaster/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not a use case which was designed into the TransformBroadcaster.  And no one has complained about CPU usage of TransformBroadcaster.

A patch which makes this behavior happen would be appreciated.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-26**:
Is this still the case with groovy, or has such a patch been written?